# Printing text into a printed text after it's printed

Tags: python, text-based

My idea was to insert a line of slow-moving text into a set of printed text after the printed text had finished printing out.

So for example:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@  SlowText  @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

The border would be printed out immediately and then the SlowText would appear after a short period,  writing out slowly.

I've tried a couple of different slow-moving text snippets to perform the actual writing. like:

```
def print_slow(txt):
    for x in txt:                    
        print(x, end='', flush=True) 
        sleep(0.1)
```

and

```
def insertedtext():
    text = " E..n..j..o..y..."
    for character in text:
        sys.stdout.write(character)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

I've tried using `'#'+ words + '#'` , tried throwing another `print("words")` in there. Heck, I even attemped at making it a variable but since I am quite new to Python I just can seem to figure it out or google it correctly enough to find it on my own. Any/all help appricated.

Comment: If the border gets printed first, you need something like `ncurses` to reposition the text cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for :

```
from time import sleep

def make_box (character, width) :
    print (character * (width + 4))
    print (character + ' ' * (width + 2) + character)
    print (character * (width + 4))

def print_slow (character, text):
    print ('\033[2A' + character, end = ' ')
    for x in text:                    
        print (x, end='', flush=True) 
        sleep (0.1)
    print ()

box_character = '@'
text = 'This is a test'
make_box (box_character, len (text))
print_slow (box_character, text)
```

The line print `('\033[2A...` moves the cursor up two lines.

Comment: That make_box is pretty neato i will admit, but sadly when i try your code it outputs this :(
```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@                                                          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
←[2A@ This is a test
```